# Configuring ELMAH Filtering Declaratively

Tags: elmah

I would like to filter the ELMAH results declaratively in my web.config. I'm not getting it to successfully filter out some of the exceptions I would like. HttpStatusCode is succesfully filtering, but I'm still getting ViewStateExceptions through. There are lots of posts about how to configure it, however I'm not sure how to put several filters into the configuration section and documentation seems to be a little thin on this point. Currently I have the below configuration in my web.config. I wondering, can someone point out:

1. If I have things defined correctly to filter out ViewStateExceptions and
2. How exactly to define the node structure to process all the filters correctly.

   ```
   <errorFilter>
       <test>
           <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
       <test>
       <test>
           <and>
               <is-type binding="Exception" type="System.Web.HttpException" />
               <regex binding='Exception.Message' pattern='invalid\s+viewstate' caseSensitive='false' />
           </and>
       </test>
       <test>
           <and>
               <is-type binding="Exception" type="System.Web.UI.ViewStateException" />
               <regex binding='Exception.Message' pattern='invalid\s+viewstate' caseSensitive='false' />
           </and>
       </test>
   </errorFilter>
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your last test try binding to BaseException, not Exception.

Re your structure try something like:

```
  <test>
    <or>
       <regex binding="BaseException.Message" pattern="Request timed out."/>
       <and>
          <equal binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['REMOTE_ADDR']" value="::1" type="String"/>
          <regex binding="Exception" pattern="hello"/>
       </and>
      <regex binding="BaseException.Message" pattern="The remote host closed the connection."/>
    </or>
  </test>
```

Should work. Wrap all the tests in an `<or>`, then any tests that must both be true, wrap in an `<and>`.

Comment: So I should have only 1 test element, and then put an or and then each of the tests. If I read you right I should do about like this:  <test><or><-test for httpstatus-><-test for next thing></or></test>, am I correct?

Comment: Did as you suggested, and it's working nicely. Between the base exception and changing to one test element, working as it should.

Comment: hey, that's good to hear. I remember getting very frustrated by binding to Exception, until I read that Elmah can wrap some exceptions, hence the need for BaseException.